# How to use julia string macros with a variable?

Tags: macros, julia

Apologies if this has already been answered, but I'm having a surprisingly hard time using the "py" string macro included with the PyCall library when I feed it a variable representing a string instead of a simple string.

Examples:

```
@py_str "2 + 2"
```

returns 4

```
z = "2 + 2"
@py_str z
```

causes a error that interpolate_pycode does not take an Expr argument, as does @py_str ($(z)).

How can I pass @py_str a string variable?

(Just to clarify - above was a toy example, I'm using it for an application where it really is necessary).

Comment: Isn't it just `py""" """` (i.e. Without the `_str`)?

Answer (score 2):

`@py_str "\$\$z"` is your friend (looked at macro help using ?@py_str in REPL). Better to write the same macro as `py"$$z"`

From the REPL help (bolded relevant part):

> py".....python code....."
>
> Evaluate the given Python code string in the main Python module.
>
> If the string is a single line (no newlines), then the Python
>   expression is evaluated and the result is returned. If the string is
>   multiple lines (contains a newline), then the Python code is compiled
>   and evaluated in the **main** Python module and nothing is   returned.
>
> If the o option is appended to the string, as in py"..."o, then the
>   return value is an unconverted PyObject; otherwise, it is
>   automatically converted to a native Julia type if possible.
>
> Any $var or $(expr) expressions that appear in the Python code
>   (except in comments or string literals) are evaluated in Julia and
>   passed   to Python via auto-generated global variables. This allows
>   you to "interpolate" Julia values into Python code.
>
> **Similarly, ny $$var or $$(expr) expressions in the Python code are
>   evaluated in Julia, converted to strings via string, and are pasted
>
>   into the Python code. This allows you to evaluate code where the code
>   itself is generated by a Julia expression.**

PS the little typo **ny** instead of **any** is in the package source.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Now I'm still having trouble with using the PyCall macro using variables.  When I try the following `py"from math import sin
       print(sin(2))"

Comment: Now I'm having trouble with calling py_str on strings representing multiline python programs, and I believe the issue has something to do with the way julia/python represent the newline character.  'When I call 'py"y = 2 + 2(newline) print(y)"` it prints 4; when I define `z = "y = 2 + 2(newline) print(y)"` and then call `py"$$z"` I get a syntax error.  Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a `pyimport` function in PyCall package. Probably it could help with the `from math...`. Also, the documentation of PyCall is quite clear, and is at: [PyCall docs](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl). In fact the first example does `@pyimport math` and uses `sin`.